# JPA - @EmbeddedId and @Id

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, composite-primary-key

This is the relevant JPA code:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class SuperClass {

  @EmbeddedId
  private FileId fileId;

  protected SuperClass() {
  }

  public SuperClass(FileId fileId) {
    this.fileId = fileId;
  }

}

@Embeddable
public class FileId {

  protected FileId() {
  }

  protected File fileName;

  public FileId(File fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }

}

@Entity
public MyClass1 extends SuperClass {

  @Id
  protected String id;

  protected MyClass1() {
  }

  public MyClass1(String id, FileId fileId) {
    super(fileId);
    this.id = id;
  }

}

@Entity
public MyClass2 extends SuperClass {

  protected MyClass2() {
  }

  public MyClass2(FileId fileId) {
    super(fileId);
  }

}
```

At runtime I get the following exception:

```
...
Exception Description: Entity class [class org.abcd.MyClass1] has both an @EmbdeddedId (on attribute [fileId]) and an @Id (on attribute [id]. Both ID types cannot be specified on the same entity.
...
```

It seems that defining a @EmbeddedId attribute (all attributes of the @Embeddable class) and a @Id attribute together as primary key is not allowed in JPA / Eclipse Link.

Does anybody know a possible solution for this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

**Some additional information:**

The class MyClassA should contain information (progress, ...; ommited in the code example above) about a certain archive file; the attribute fileId of the super class SuperClass is used to identify this file. Currently fileId (the id-class FileId) only consists of the file name, but later more attributes will be added.

MyClassB contains information about a file IN the archive. This file will be identified with the atttribute id (its the relative path in the archive) and fileId of the super class SuperClass.

I think of the following database structure:

Table "MyClass1":

fileName | id | ...

Table "MyClass2":

fileName | ...

I hope now it's a bit more clear what I exactly want :).

Comment: If you are unable to use the parent's Id in the child's class, then you have two things to consider: 1. Does your structure make sense? ; 2) Does the Id belong in the parent?

Comment: Your code has `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, but your error has `MyClassA`. This tells me that you are not showing us your actual code, which makes me said because that makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping doesn't make any sense. You DO have an `@EmbeddedId` and an `@Id` in the same class: your `MyClassA` has na `@Id` and it extends a SuperClass which already has an `@EmbeddedId`. I don't know why you would want that? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Beder, I have added some information in the question to make my design decisions more understandable.

Comment: By the structure you described seems like you're looking for a 1x1 or a 1xn relationship, in which case you should use a JOIN between MyClassA and SuperClass, and MyClassB and SuperClass. They have their own unique ids (primary keys) and you have 3 tables (File, MyClassA and MyClassB). MyClassA and MyClassB will both have a @JoinColumn with File. Makes sense? Maybe write down your database structure first to figure out the best way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Yes, the object model looks wrong. I think there should be an `ArchiveFile` class, identified by the name and whatever other details, and a `FileInArchiveFile` class, where there is a `@OneToMany` relationship from the former to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As guys recommended you - maybe changing of the data models will give you more sense here.

And here is my simple proposal :

A Basic class entity containing an ID field and get/set-tters 
like :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Entity { 

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private int id;

     // getters/setters
}
```

This could be used for basic class for all entities in you model. 
Then following your functional requirements maybe next could help you:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOIN)
public class File extends Entity {

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String fileName;

    // other future columns you mention above
}

@Entity
public class ArchiveFile extends File {

    // other information here - progress and so on 
}

@Entity
public class ArchiveFileTracker extends Entity {

    @OneToMany
    private ArchiteFile architeFile;

    // other specific information here 
}
```

I hope this could covers your requirements.

Good luck, 
Simeon